# How do I read in columns of data into a while loop when converting ASCII file to NetCDF?

Tags: matlab, loops, ascii, netcdf

I'm trying to convert a large ASCII file into a NetCDF through MATLAB. It's a climate file 15329 x 16 columns.

```
nccreate('monthly_tmp.nc', 'monthly_temperatures', 'Dimensions', {'ff' 12 'lon' 180  'lat' 180}, 'Format','classic') 
fid=fopen('tmp.mat');
var=zeros(12); 
while ~feof(fid) 
    coor=fscanf(fid, '%d', 2); 
    var=fscanf(fid, '%f', inf); 
    lat=coor(1); lon=coor(2);
    ncwrite('monthly_tmp.nc', 'monthly_temperatures', var (1 lat, lon));
end
```

the columns are set out as latitude, longitude, year and 12 monthly values.

I need to first read lat and lon and then assign a monthly value to that grid.

So I need columns 1 and 2, and then 4-15 for my temperature values.

I'm really stuck with how I can feed my variables into the while loop!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is `tmp.mat` a normal matlab data file? If so, you need to `load` the `.mat` file instead of trying to `fopen` it. After loading, you will end up with a single  `15329 x 16` variable. You can do a for loop for each row and write the data the way you want.

Comment: I have already loaded up the file into matlab. Therefore would i be able to just open it within the code as it is already loaded into it?